# Event on click jquery doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a project using jquery 1.10.2.

It adds comments when you click on a submit button. It creates the comments with javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enviar").on('click',function(){
        var texto=$("#comentarios").val();
        var fecha= new Date();
        var cruz= "<img class='eliminar' src='error.png'>"+"</img>";
        var fechaComentario= "<span class='fecha'>"+fecha.getHours()+":"+fecha.getMinutes()+":"+fecha.getSeconds()+"</span>";
        var divComentarioEscrito= "<div class='comentario-enviado'>";
        var divCompleto= divComentarioEscrito+fechaComentario+"   "+texto+"   "+cruz+"</div>";
            $("#comentarios-escritos").prepend(divCompleto);
    });
    $(".eliminar").on('click',function(){
       alert("DELETEEEE");
    });
});
```

I want to get the alert "DELETEEE" but it doesnt work.

I tried to use `.live` jquery function and it didnt work also.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are appending your elements after the page has loaded you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enviar").on('click',function(){
        var texto = $("#comentarios").val();
        var fecha = new Date();
        var cruz = "<img class='eliminar' src='error.png'></img>";
        var fechaComentario = "<span class='fecha'>" + fecha.getHours() + ":" + fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha.getSeconds() + "</span>";
        var divComentarioEscrito = "<div class='comentario-enviado'>";
        var divCompleto = divComentarioEscrito + fechaComentario + "   " + texto + "   " + cruz + "</div>";
        $("#comentarios-escritos").prepend(divCompleto);
    });

    // Note the amended selector here...
    $("#comentarios-escritos").on('click', '.eliminar', function(){
       alert("DELETEEEE");
    });
});
```

Also, instead of building and appending a massive string, you can use jQuery to manipulate the DOM, which should be quicker:

```
$("#enviar").on('click', function() {
    var $div = $('<div />', { "class": "comentario-enviado" }).prependTo("#comentarios-escritos");
    var fecha = new Date();
    $div.append($('<span />', { "class": "fecha", "text": fecha.getHours() + ":" + fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha.getSeconds() });
    $div.append($("#comentarios").val());
    $div.append($('<img />', { "class": "eliminar", "src": "error.png" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 $('#comentarios-escritos').on("click","img", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('DELETEEEE');
 });
```